# How to iterate over a list, modify it but avoid an error?

Tags: python, list

I have two variable lenght lists extracted from an excel file. One has wagon number and the other the wagon weight, something like this:

```
wagon_list = [1234567, 2345678, 3456789, 4567890]
weight_list = [1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4]
```

Sometimes the wagon_list will have a duplicate number, I need to sum the wagon weight and remove the duplicate from both:

```
wagon_list = [1234567, 2345678, 2345678, 4567890]
weight_list = [1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4]
```

should become:

```
wagon_list = [1234567, 2345678, 4567890]
weight_list = [1.1, 5.5, 4.4]
```

My first option was to pop items and sum them while iterating with a for loop. It didnt work because (after some research) you cant change a list youre iterating over.
So I moved to the second option, using an auxiliary list. It doesnt work when it hits the last index. Even after some tweaking of my code, I cant find a solution.

I can see it would have further problems if the last three elements were to be added.

```
counter_3 = 0

for i in wagon_list:

    if i == wagon_list[-1]: #last entry, simply appends to the new list. This comes first because the next option returns error if running the last entry as i
        new_wagon_list.append(wagon_list[counter_3])
        new_weight_list.append(weight_list[counter_3])
        counter_3 +=2

    elif i != wagon_list[(counter_3 + 1)]: #if they are different, appends.
        new_wagon_list.append(wagon_list[counter_3])
        new_weight_list.append(weight_list[counter_3])
        counter_3 += 1

    elif i == wagon_list[(counter_3 + 1)]: #if equal to next item, appends the wagon and sums the weights
        new_wagon_list.append(wagon_list[counter_3])
        new_weight_list.append(weight_list[counter_3] + weight_list[counter_3 + 1])
```

This should return:

```
wagon_list = [1234567, 2345678, 4567890]
weight_list = [1.1, 5.5, 4.4]
```

But returns

```
wagon_list = [1234567, 2345678, 3456789, 3456789, 3456789]
weight_list = [1.1, 2.2, 7.7, 7.7, 3.3]
```

Comment: It would be much easier to use a `dict` to sum up the weights for each wagon.  That also allows the `wagon_list` to be unsorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple way, using `defaultdict` (hence the result is correct even if `wagon_list` is unordered). You could also use `groupby` but then you have to sort both lists so that duplicate wagons are consecutive.

This solution requires a single pass through the lists, and doesn't change the order of the lists. It just removes duplicate wagons and adds their weight.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

def group_weights(wagon_list, weight_list):
    ww = defaultdict(float)
    for wagon, weight in zip(wagon_list, weight_list):
        ww[wagon] += weight

    return list(ww), list(ww.values())
```

**Example**

```py
# set up MRE

wagon_list = [1234567, 2345678, 2345678, 4567890]
weight_list = [1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4]

new_wagon_list, new_weight_list = group_weights(wagon_list, weight_list)

>>> new_wagon_list
[1234567, 2345678, 4567890]

>>> new_weight_list
[1.1, 5.5, 4.4]
```

**Addendum**

If you'd like to avoid `defaultdict` altogether, you can also simply do this (same result as above):

```py
ww = {}
for k, v in zip(wagon_list, weight_list):
    ww[k] = ww.get(k, 0) + v
new_wagon_list, new_weight_list = map(list, zip(*ww.items()))
```

**Explanation**

A quick review of some of the tools and syntax used above:

- [`zip(*iterables)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) "Make an iterator that aggregates elements from each of the iterables." So e.g.:

  ```py
  for x, y in zip(wagon_list, weight_list):
      print(f'x={x}, y={y}')
  # prints out
  x=1234567, y=1.1
  x=2345678, y=2.2
  x=2345678, y=3.3
  x=4567890, y=4.4
  ```
- [`dict.get(key[, default])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) "Return the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else default." In other words, with `ww[k] = ww.get(k, 0) + v`, we are saying: add `v` to `ww[k]`, but if it doesn't exist yet, then use `0` as a starting point.
- The last bit (`new_wagon_list, new_weight_list = map(list, zip(*ww.items()))`) uses the idiom that "`zip()` in conjunction with the `*` operator can be used to unzip a list" (or, in this case, an iterator of tuples `key, value` obtained from `dict.items()`). Without the `map(list, ...)`, we would get tuples in the two variables. I thought you may want to stick with lists, so we apply `list(.)` to each tuple before assigning to `new_wagon_list` resp. `new_weight_list`.

Comment: Pierre thank you for the solution. It worked great, I decided to use the second option and avoid importing anything else.
The only problem is: I didnt understand ANYTHING you did. Could you elaborate on that answer with comments on each operation?

Comment: I added an explanation -- please see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I ran the code in Thonny and python tutor but I'm having a hard time understanding it. Probably because its way above my knowledge.
For now I'll accept it works in a misterious way and will keep developing my python skills. Thanks alot!!

Answer (score 1):

Modifying a list that you're iterating over doesn't work out well.  I'd zip the two lists together and use `itertools.groupby`:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> wagon_list = [1234567, 2345678, 2345678, 4567890]
>>> weight_list = [1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4]
>>> wagon_list, weight_list = map(list, zip(*(
...     (wagon, sum(weight for _, weight in group))
...     for wagon, group in groupby(sorted(
...         zip(wagon_list, weight_list)
...     ), key=lambda t: t[0])
... )))
>>> wagon_list
[1234567, 2345678, 4567890]
>>> weight_list
[1.1, 5.5, 4.4]
```

Comment: I also considered `groupby`, but it requires sorting, and will affect the order of the result lists.

Comment: If you're removing/merging some of the items, it's impossible to preserve ordering anyway, so my preference (unless there's a really specific need otherwise) would be to sort it and explicitly state in the interface that this processing will result in a sorted and deduped list, rather than have the caller expect that the original ordering will be preserved.  If we only want to merge *adjacent* duplicates we could skip the sort, and the *relative* ordering (but not the original indices!) would be preserved, but again, the interface would need to make that clear.

Comment: The answers based on `dict` preserve the order of appearance and remove duplicates. Like Linux's `uniq`, or `pandas`'s `pd.unique()` or `Series.drop_duplicates()` (with the default `keep='first'`). It is wasteful to sort in order to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary to combine the values:

```
In [1]: wagon_list = [1234567, 2345678, 2345678, 4567890]
   ...: weight_list = [1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4]
Out[1]: [1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4]

In [2]: together = {}
Out[2]: {}

In [3]: for k, v in zip(wagon_list, weight_list):
   ...:     together[k] = together.setdefault(k, 0) + v
   ...:     

In [4]: together
Out[4]: {1234567: 1.1, 2345678: 5.5, 4567890: 4.4}

In [6]: new_wagon_list = list(together.keys())
Out[6]: [1234567, 2345678, 4567890]

In [7]: new_weight_list = list(together.values())
Out[7]: [1.1, 5.5, 4.4]
```

Answer (score 1):

No fluff, frills, dependency or mystery version. Either an index for the current wagon is going to be found, allowing us to pinpoint the weight index to modify or no index is found and we append both of the new values.

Your entire problem revolves around "Does this already exist?". When using any `Iterable`, we can answer that question with `index`. `index` throws an `Exception` if no index is found so, we wrap it in `try` and treat `except` as an `else`.

```
def wagon_filter(wagons:list, weights:list) -> tuple:
    #pre-zip and clear so we can reuse the references
    data   = zip(wagons, weights)
    wagons, weights = [], []
    
    #reassign
    for W, w in data:
        try:      #(W)agon exists? modify it's (w)eight index
            i = wagons.index(W)
            weights[i] += w
        except:   #else append new (W)agon and (w)eight
            wagons.append(W)
            weights.append(w)
     
    return wagons, weights
```

---

usage:

```
#data
wagons  = [1234567, 2345678, 2345678, 4567890]
weights = [1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4]

#print filter results
print(*wagon_filter(wagons, weights), sep='\n')

#[1234567, 2345678, 4567890]
#[1.1, 5.5, 4.4]
```